# Updating a database in a server using command-line

Tags: mysql, database, command-line, database-administration

I have been searching for a while to find a good answer to my problem. 
I have a new server where I would like to run a script in `.php` which uses a database to store some data. What I have done so far is:

1. Place the .php file in the server with the help of Putty.
2. Create a database in phpmyadmin, export it and place it in the same folder of my project in putty.
3. Run `php5 crawl.php > logfile.log 2&>1&`

but it doesn't update the database.

I am little bit confused with the steps I have to make in order to make it work. I have been reading also this article http://www.aspkin.com/using-putty-to-import-a-database/ but when I run the

```
mysql -u dbusername -p databasename < backupname.sql
```

I get this error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

if it's a local machine you may not have a password on it for root - so remove the -p tag.

Otherwise you want to specify the password in there with it, without a space, like so:

mysql -u dbusername -pYourPassword databasename < backupname.sql

Comment: I get the same error, even if I don't use Password. I think that something else might be wrong, but since I am new at this, I can't find out.

Comment: Is this your local machine or a remote server?

Comment: Can you perform a login to your database on the command line? mysql -u dbusername -p OR mysql -u dbusername

Answer (score 0):

```
zcat /path/to/file.sql.gz | mysql -uroot -p your_database
```

Comment: may be some explanation on this code instead of just pasting it here?